# Query returns multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently studying SQL Server `INNER JOIN`.

The query returns multiple quantity values, but I want the quantity per item with the size and color, and the result value is called several times for the color and size per item.

I want the quantity of item per size and color.

I tried this but it returns same quantity values multiple times.

```
SELECT
    Product.Id,
    Product.Sku,
    Product.[Name] AS ProductName,
    a.[Name] AS Color,
    b.[Name] AS Size,
    ProductAttributeCombination.StockQuantity
FROM 
    Product
INNER JOIN 
    Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON Product.Id = m1.ProductId
INNER JOIN 
    productAttributeValue a ON m1.Id = a.ProductAttributeMappingId
INNER JOIN 
    Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON Product.Id = m2.ProductId
INNER JOIN 
    productAttributeValue b ON m2.Id = b.ProductAttributeMappingId
INNER JOIN 
    ProductAttributeCombination ON Product.Id = ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId 
WHERE 
    m1.ProductAttributeId = 1 
    AND m2.ProductAttributeId = 8 
    AND Product.Deleted = 0
```

Values returned from this query are:

```
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre         S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre         M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre         L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED         L   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE L   236
```

and so on.

Also, I have tried using GROUP BY, but it returns same total sum values.

```
SELECT
    Product.Id,
    Product.Sku,
    Product.[Name] AS ProductName,
    a.[Name] AS Color,
    b.[Name] AS Size,
    SUM(ProductAttributeCombination.StockQuantity) AS TotalStockQuantity
FROM 
    Product
LEFT JOIN 
    Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON Product.Id = m1.ProductId
LEFT JOIN 
    productAttributeValue a ON m1.Id = a.ProductAttributeMappingId
LEFT JOIN 
    Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON Product.Id = m2.ProductId
LEFT JOIN 
    productAttributeValue b ON m2.Id = b.ProductAttributeMappingId
LEFT JOIN 
    ProductAttributeCombination ON Product.Id = ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId 
WHERE 
    m1.ProductAttributeId = 1 
    AND m2.ProductAttributeId = 8 
    AND Product.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY 
    Product.Id, Product.Sku, Product.[Name], a.[Name], b.[Name];
```

The values returned from this query are:

```
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK           L   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE L   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE M   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE S   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre     L   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre     M   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   pre     S   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED     L   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED     M   1800
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   RED     S   1800
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK       L   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK       M   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     BLACK       S   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK L   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK M   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     LIGHT BLACK S   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED     L   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED     M   1295
58  TEST_0006   Romper (Broken)     RED     S   1295
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK       L   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE L   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE M   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   BLACK/WHITE S   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED     L   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED     M   1752
63  NEW TEST    Maxi Dress (Pack)   RED     S   1752
```

Comment: You say you expect a returned row per size and colour... which is what you are getting in your first results? Its not clear what the issue is.

Comment: You haven't showed us your table definitions, but I am guessing you are not being specific enough in your joins i.e. (maybe) `ProductAttributeCombination ` should also be joined on colour and size...

Comment: It's not multiple times: there are three different sizes, S M and L, for each. Sample input data and expected results woul help immensely.

Comment: you need to pivot/unpivot the data using TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the duplicates below:

```
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       L   236
.......
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       S   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       M   236
57  TEST_0005   Wrap Dress (Pack)   BLACK       L   236
```

This is the result of either a "weak" join or poorly normalized tables.
"Weak" join is when you do not join two tables on all of the join keys but only some of them.

The way to debug this is to replace your select column list with `*` to return all columns and carefully compare the data.

I would also suggest adding where conditions to restrict your results to a few known duplicate cases to reduce noise.

Example:

```
SELECT
    -- We want all columns returned to find out the missing "unique" keys
    *
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m1 ON Product.Id = m1.ProductId
INNER JOIN productAttributeValue a ON m1.Id = a.ProductAttributeMappingId
INNER JOIN Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping m2 ON Product.Id = m2.ProductId
INNER JOIN productAttributeValue b ON m2.Id = b.ProductAttributeMappingId
INNER JOIN ProductAttributeCombination ON Product.Id = ProductAttributeCombination.ProductId 
WHERE m1.ProductAttributeId = 1 AND m2.ProductAttributeId = 8 AND Product.Deleted = 0
-- We are only looking at one example of the duplicate values
AND Product.id = 57
```

Note: it is also possible that you are missing a whole "discriminator" table in your `FROM` joins.

If your check has not uncovered anything of value that you need to check individual tables for duplicate values e.g. check how many rows are returned for `Product` table: `SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Product.Id = 57` and so on for each table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping
-- Check this for each ProductAttributeId 
WHERE ProductAttributeId = 1 AND ProductId = 57
```

etc.

My guess is that you are missing join conditions on `ProductAttributeCombination` table BUT it is only a guess

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the exact return values until with Product.Sku, ProductAttributeCombination.StockQuantity and ProductAttribute_Mapping.ProductAttributeId but the return values increase when I add ProductAttributeValue. So I believe the ProductAttributeValue INNER JOIN is causing an error but I got stuck from here.

Product is the Primary key.
ProductAttributeCombination contains ProductId Foreign Key.
Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping contains ProductId and ProductAttributeId Foreign Keys.
ProductAttributeValue contains Product_ProductAttribute_Mapping Foreign Key.

Comment: You will need to modify your question to add table definitions and the output when all columns are included. `ProductAttributeCombination.StockQuantity` - you join it only on `ProductID`. Should it not be joined on `ProductAttributeId` as well? You want to get stock for each kind of product, right?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Did my answer help you?

Answer (score -1):

You can not includ the Product.Id in GROUP BY, this will breake the groups because every line will have a diferent grouping result.

Also looks like some JOIN are duplicating the results, maybe you will need to make a subquery to get the Color and Size to avoid this.